# extracting the middle term of $ (z \cos \theta + w\sin \theta )^m(- z\sin \theta + w\cos \theta )^m $

Tags: trigonometry, representation-theory, generating-functions

Is there a systematic way to extract the middle term of the following expression?

$$ (z \cos \theta  + w\sin \theta )^m(- z\sin \theta  + w\cos \theta )^m $$

This is homogeneous polynomial of degree $2m$, so I am looking for the $(zw)^m$ term.

---

Example $m = 2$:

$$ (z \cos \theta  + w\sin \theta )^2(- z\sin \theta  + w\sin \theta )^2
= \dots + (zw)^2(\cos^4 \theta - 4 \cos^2 \theta \sin^2 \theta + \sin^4 \theta) + \dots $$

The middle terms can be simplified using the cosine double angle formulas.

\begin{eqnarray}\cos^4 \theta - 4 \cos^2 \theta \sin^2 \theta + \sin^4 \theta
&=& (\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta)^2 - 2 \cos^2 \theta \sin^2 \theta \\
&=& \cos^2 2\theta - \tfrac{1}{2}\sin^2 2\theta \\
&=& \boxed{\tfrac{3}{2}\cos^2 2\theta - \tfrac{1}{2}}
\end{eqnarray}

Is it true this middle term can always be expanded as a polynomial in $x=\cos 2\theta$?

---

I learned of this trick while studying the [Wigner D-matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix).  It says the Legendre polynomials are certain matrix elements in the representation theory of $SU(2)$.  Checking this fact was surprisingly hard.

Comment: Maybe the title could also be corrected?

Answer (score 2):

We use the binomial theorem, to see that
$$
(z\cos\theta+w\sin\theta)^m = \sum_{k=0}^m {m\choose k}z^{m-k}\cos^{m-k}\theta \,w^k\sin^k\theta
$$
and
$$
(-z\sin\theta+w\cos\theta)^m=\sum_{k=0}^m {m\choose k}(-z)^k\sin^k\theta\,w^{m-k}\cos^{m-k}\theta.
$$
Written this way, I think it is clear that when we multiply these factors together, the coefficient in front of $z^mw^m$ becomes 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k{m\choose k}^2 (\cos^{2}\theta)^{m-k}(\sin^2\theta)^k.
$$
Next, since $\cos^2\theta=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos2\theta)$ and $\sin^2\theta=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos2\theta)$ this simplifies into
$$
\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k{m\choose k}^2 \bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}(1+\cos2\theta)\bigr]^{m-k}\bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}(1-\cos2\theta)\bigr]^k,
$$
a polynomial in $\cos2\theta$.

**A check of the case $m=2$**

In this case, the formula gives
$$
\begin{align}
&(-1)^0{2\choose 0}^2\bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}(1+\cos2\theta)\bigr]^2\\
&+(-1)^1{2\choose 1}^2\tfrac{1}{2}(1+\cos2\theta)\tfrac{1}{2}(1-\cos2\theta)\\
&+(-1)^2{2\choose 2}^2\bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}(1-\cos2\theta)\bigr]^2\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\cos^22\theta-\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Continuing mickep's answer, these are, indeed, the [Legendre Polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials)
$$
\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k{m\choose k}^2 \bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}(1+\cos2\theta)\bigr]^{m-k}\bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}(1-\cos2\theta)\bigr]^k
= P_m(\cos(2\theta))
$$

Comment: Ah nice! I should probably have known about this.